# Equally divide area under a curve

Tags: algorithm, math, nonlinear-optimization

I have a y = sin(x) curve and x is between 0 and pi (first quadrant - no negative values). Something like this:

[image]

I want to **equally** divide area under the curve to **n** pieces and get the (biggest) x value for each piece.

Any ideas would be appreciated for an algorithm.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What are you trying to do, and what have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The area under the curve is its integral. The integral of `sin(x)` from `0` to `u` is `1-cos(u)`, so the integral from `0` to `π`is `2`. Inverting that formula finds the points `t` for which `u` gets a certain value. So, we're looking for the values `t=acos(1-u)` for the values of `u` that divide `[0, 2]` into `n` equal parts.

In code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-0.2, 3.3, 500)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)

n = 7
u = np.linspace(0, 2, n + 1, endpoint=True)
t = np.arccos(1 - u)
print("The limits of the areas are:", list(t))

colors = plt.cm.Set2.colors
for i in range(n):
    filter = (x > t[i]) & (x <= t[i + 1])
    plt.fill_between(x[filter], 0, y[filter], color=colors[i])
plt.xticks(t)
plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_color('none')
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_color('none')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not entirely consequent answer, maybe it would be interesting.
Deviding the area in question into three equal parts.
On the basis OA, as on the hypotenuse, build a right angled triangle with the ratio of the legs OC:AC= 4:5. Raise the vertical from the point C. Shift that vertical symmetrically also to the righy side. Division completed. Error about 1%.
Now on the merits/ One must use a recurrent formulae: X0= 0, X(i+1)= X(i)+Δ(i+1); Δ(i+1)= arccossqrt((p(i))^2-q(i))-p(i)), where p(i)= cos(X(i))(2/n-cos(X(i)); q(i)= cos(2X(i))+4/n(1/n-cos(X(i))

Comment: Oh my God! How artifically I have complicated the problem! It must be the answer: X(0)= 0;  Δ(i)= X(i)-X(i-1); X9i)= arccos(1-2i/n).